# TFS 2013 API Project Creation

Tags: api, tfs

Can't seem to find an answer to this on MSDN or on here, does the Team Foundation Server 2013 API expose any methods to allow Project Creation? and if so in which classes?

Comment: Information about this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb046e13-3712-4c6c-8dd3-fd57a8f7833b/how-to-create-team-project-wiht-tfs-api-in-tfs2010?forum=tfsadmin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: project creation is a complex process involving many modules (DLLs). In fact, it requires Visual Studio (or Team Explorer) the same or newer version of TFS.

If you need to automate, you may use the [tfpt createteamproject](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) command line tool.

*Update 2016-07-22*: Since TFS 2015 Update 2 it is possible to create a project using the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects).