# Automate git repository creation on TFS 2013

Tags: git, tfs, automation

So, there's a sizable Gitorious installation, with hundreds of (mostly small) repositories. Management wants to combine TFS and Git on the same infrastructure, since TFS 2013 supports git repositories. That means we need to migrate hosts/servers.

But .. so far I fail to find a way to create git repositories that *doesn't* involve me clicking literally hundreds of times on 'Create new repository'. I need some way to automate this process, allowing me to create repositories in an existing team project.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073451/tfs-2013-api-project-creation) I can automate team project creation using the tfs power tools - but I cannot find anything related to repositories.

I'm fine with cli tools, powershell, building something in C# - I just fail to find the right keywords or some documentation that might make this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never attempted, but a route could be:

1. Create the project via `tfpt creatteamproject` specifying `/sourcecontrol:None`
2. Calling the [new REST API](http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-git-repositories-vsi) to create Git repos within the project

Let us know if this works.

**UPDATE:** I had a chance to test this myself and my solution works also on premise. All details are in [my post](http://blog.casavian.eu/2014/10/28/automating-project-creation/) and is based on the `CreateTeamProjectRepository.GitRepositoryService` method.

Comment: Aha! Creating a project isn't a big deal/optional/out of scope, but the REST API link was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tested, works fine. Gotchas were 1) that I wanted to script that using curl or similar and at first I failed to make the authentication work (curl defaults to basic authentication and seems to complately ignore NTLM without an explicit --ntlm flag) and 2) that the project guid is needed (so you need to grab that from somewhere first). Works like a charm.

Comment: Please share with the community with a blog post or pushing the code in a public repo. I can help you in case.
When done, add a link here.